# how to remove the last digit to the left of the cursor in EditText

Tags: java, android, substring, cursor-position

I am was making a DEL button which would delete 1 char at a time. I recently added cursor movement to delete in between bud don't know how

I used substrings for deleting normally. It would crash if the number of chars was 0 or 1 before pressing it. I added if statement to fix it.

Here is my delete method

```java
 public void delete(View view){
        if(textArea.length()==0){
            return;
        }else if(textArea.length()==1){
            if(textArea.getSelectionStart()==textArea.length()){
                textArea.setText("");
            }else{
                return;
            }

        }else {
            int selection = textArea.getSelectionStart();
            textArea.setText(textArea.getText().delete(Math.max(0, selection - 1), selection));
        }
    }
```

Please Tell How I could Do This To Delete the Char immediately left to the cursor.

I edited the code for the answerer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `delete` method of `Editable` class like this

```
 public void delete(View view){
    int selection = textArea.getSelectionStart();
    textArea.setText(textArea.getText().delete(Math.max(0, selection - 1), selection));
}
```

Comment: What does Math.max does??And please explain the params of delete method.

Comment: I should put it inside textArea.setText();  (Just To Prevent Errors)

Comment: It returns the greater of two values.

Comment: It is only deleting it the first time then it does nothing

Comment: I removed the substring statement in else and put your code.

Comment: You should replace whole code you provided, otherwise it won't work for text with length < 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194644/discussion-between-demon-app-programmer-and-electroweak).